# Sforno to Tehillim 69:3

Tags: commentaries, tehilim-psalms

Is Sforno to Tehillim available anywhere online?    I would like to know his commentary to Tehillim 69:3.  Edit, I found it on http://www.hebrewbooks.org/42435 but it is published in 1586 and basically impossible to read.  If anyone can decipher it can you please translate it here, thanks.

Comment: It is not impossible to read, you need a little training

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with (from [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42435&st=&pgnum=76)):

טָבַ֤עְתִּי ׀ בִּיוֵ֣ן מְ֭צוּלָה -- שהיא מלכות בבל שהיא במצולה כאמרו האומר לצולה חרבי

וְאֵ֣ין מָעֳמָ֑ד -- שנהרג גדליה בן אחיקם שנשאר פּקיד בארץ

בָּ֥אתִי בְמַעֲמַקֵּי־מַ֝֗יִם -- בימי יוני' שהיו עמקי לב

וְשִׁבֹּ֥לֶת שְׁטָפָֽתְנִי -- אחר שנמלטתי מאלו המלכים הגדולים שטפתני שבולת מים זה העם לא היה שהיא מלכות פּרס שקראום ז"ל מלכו' שאינה הוגנת כי אמנם היא שטפתני והגלתני מארצי

Comment: The question seems to be asking for a translation

Comment: @ba I'm not clear on that -- at first the concern is that it is impossible to read because it was published in 1586 so I assumed it was a legibility issue and the 'translation' request was more a transcription (and transfer from Rashi script). There was no request that the Sforno to Tehillim IN ENGLISH be found online. If the requester just wants a translation, then why ask for it on line and not just ask for an explanation?

Comment: I had read "If anyone can decipher it can you please translate it here, thanks." Interpret it however you think is right

Comment: @rosends   thanks a lot. I was mistaken though because I actually want Sforno’s commentary to the entire Psalm 69, as he analyzes every word and relates it to a different facet in Israel’s long exile. So if you could do for the whole chapter 69 what you did for 69:3 that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @rosends never mind.  I found it in a printed mikra'os gedolos.  Thanks.